# Accessing remote SQL Server database

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection

I'm trying to access the mssql database of my website which a web design team has designed. They have given me the ip, port, db name, user and password... but how can I connect to the mssql server?

I have tried doing it via php but I think I have to compile php without "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql"... which I would not rather do on this windows 7 computer unless I have to.

I've tried SQL Server Management Studio Express but I couldn't find a way to access to a REMOTE database.

I've also tried Razor SQL but that did not connect either.

I almost tried something like phpmyadmin for asp.net but wanted to find an easier solution for this- without installing asp.net.

So what would be a good solution for managing a remote mssql database? Is there a program like Office Access that can handle such job?

Comment: php or asp.net please decide :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a fan of Navicat:

http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_sqlserver/sqlserver_detail_win.html

However, I have not used the Sql Server version, but the MySQL and Oracle versions are pretty good - MySQL is awesome (mid range price point is the only draw back).

However Navicat Lite, which is still pretty good (and can handle most server types) is free!

Just a note, has the remote DB been setup for remote connections? If not you will not be able to get access no matter what you use.

Comment: yup they have given me access for my static ip

Comment: cool, if you go the Navicat route, try the lite version, it can connect to anything, but is less feature rich. Again, I can't say I have connected to SQl Server with it, but it is worth a  shot.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server Management studio does support remote connections, in the small dialog you see in the middle of the screen when you run it, specify IP, username and password.

do you get any error? Which error do you get?

Comment: http://goo.gl/Y7vkQ server name: is where the ip goes then? or some field here? http://goo.gl/4Tyag the error i get is this: `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)`